# Gradient of Distant Function

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am learning the Hessian comparison theorem on Riemannian manifold. It refers to the gradient of distant function.

Fix $x\in M$. Let $\rho(y)=d(y,x)$, and $r:I\to M$ is a minimal geodesic curve with $r(0)=x$. Namely $d(r(t),x)=|r'(0)|t$.

So can we get the conclusion 
$$\text{grad}\rho=r'$$

Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\nabla \rho$ is the dual of $d\rho$ under the metric $g$. But by Gauss's lemma, we know that

$$\left\langle\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}, \frac{\partial }{\partial \rho}\right\rangle = 1,\ \ \ \ \left\langle\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}, \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_i}\right\rangle = 0,$$ where $\theta_i, i = 1, \cdots, n-1$ are coordinate under the geodesic polar coordinate. Thus

$$\nabla \rho = g^{11} \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} g^{1i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_i} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}$$

as $g^{11} = 1$, $g^{1i} = 0$.

Note that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}$ is in general **not** the $r'$ you wrote down. In particular, you did not tell what $|r'(0)|$ is. If $|r'(0)| = 1$, then they are the same.